# How to create a CSV matrix based on csv file?

Tags: python, csv, matrix

I just learn python and I don't know where to start and go with my current project. I got a project to make a matrix that can show relation between color from a .csv file to another .csv file. The input and output file will be looked like this

> Input
>
> ```
> black blue
> red blue
> blue black
> yellow black
> ```
>
> Output
>
> ````
>              black   blue   red   yellow
> black          0      1      0      1
> blue           1      0      1      0
> red            0      1      0      0
> yellow         1      0      0      0
> ?```
> ````

By using this code, but .csv output doesn't show anything.

```
import csv
import collections
import itertools

grid = collections.Counter()

with open("color.csv", "r", newline="") as fp:
    reader = csv.reader(fp)
    for line in reader:
        line = [name.strip() for name in line if name.strip()]
        if len(line) == 1:
            grid[line[0], line[0]] += 1

relations = sorted(set(pair[0] for pair in grid))

with open("color_sorted.csv", "w", newline="") as fp:
    writer = csv.writer(fp)
    writer.writerow([''] + relations)
    for relation in relations:
        line = [relation,] + [grid[relation, other] for other in relations]
        writer.writerow(line)
```

Comment: What code have you tried? And is this a homework problem?

Comment: I have only try python, sort off. I use python because i have to convert it again to csv

Comment: Generally, on Stack Overflow, if someone asks what code you've tried, the expectation is that you edit your question to show that code. Saying that you've just tried Python isn't helpful.

Comment: Implement the matrix as a 2-dimensional array initialized with zeros. Then considering the colors as names of numerical horizontal and vertical indices into that array, you need to process each pair of input colors to effectively set `matrix[black][blue] = 1`, `matrix[red][blue] = 1`, etc.

Comment: @jjramsey I see, have edit it, and post the code that I had tried but doesn't show anything.

Comment: You'll also need to write the matrix out as a csv file after filling in its data — forgot to put that step in at the end.